# Heston: Variance of Integrated Variance

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, variance, heston

Consider the standard Heston model\begin{align*}
dX&=\left(r-\frac{1}{2}v\right)dt+\sqrt{v}dB,\\
dv&=\kappa(\theta-v)dt+\xi\sqrt{v}dW, \\
dBdW&=\rho dt.
\end{align*}
Computing $\mathbb{E}\int_0^t v_sds$ is simple but does anyone have a reference for
\begin{align}
Var\left(\int_0^t v_sds\right)
\end{align}
or is there a simple trick to solve this integral and compute its second moment?

---

Using Ito's Lemma ($d(tv)=vdt+tdv$) and using the SDE for $dv$, I only got
\begin{align}
\int_0^t v_udu=tv_t-\frac{1}{2}\kappa\theta t^2+\kappa\int_0^t u v_udu-\xi\int_0^t u\sqrt{v_u}dW_u,
\end{align}
which doesn't look too helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Studying zero-coupon bond prices in the CIR (1985) short rate model, $\text{d}r_t=\kappa(\theta-r_t)\text{d}t+\xi\sqrt{r_t}\text{d}W_t$, [Hirsa (2013, Section 1.2.6.2)](https://www.routledge.com/Computational-Methods-in-Finance/Hirsa/p/book/9781439829578) states that the characteristic function of the realised interest rate $R_t=\int_0^t r_s\text{d}s$ is
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{R_t}(u)=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{iuR_t}\right] = A_t(u)e^{B_t(u)r_0},
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
A_t(u) &= \frac{\exp\left(\frac{\kappa^2\theta t}{\xi^2}\right)}{\left(\cosh\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma t\right)+\frac{\kappa}{\gamma}\sinh\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma t\right)\right)^{2\kappa\theta/\xi^2}}, \\
B_t(u) &= \frac{2iu}{\kappa+\gamma\coth\left(\frac{1}{2}\gamma t\right)},\\
\gamma &= \sqrt{\kappa^2-2\xi^2iu}.
\end{align*}

---

As you say, $\mathbb{E}[R_t]$ can be easily computed using Fubini's theorem but from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Moments) you also have $$\mathbb{E}[R_t]=-i\varphi_{R_t}'(0).$$ The variance is
\begin{align}
\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[R_t] &= \mathbb{E}[R_t^2] - \mathbb{E}[R_t]^2 \\
&=-\varphi_{R_t}''(0) + \varphi_{R_t}'(0)^2.
\end{align}
Computing these derivatives may be ugly. You could use finite differences instead, $$\mathbb{E}[R_t^2]\approx-\frac{\varphi_{R_t}(-h)-2\varphi_{R_t}(0)+\varphi_{R_t}(h)}{h^2}=\frac{2-\varphi_{R_t}(-h)-\varphi_{R_t}(h)}{h^2}.$$

---

**Note** A similar term to $\gamma$ appears in the characteristic function of the log stock price of the Heston (1993) model. One needs to be careful with the sign of the root (``little Heston trap''). I'm not sure whether the same applies here.

Comment: Ah yes, for CIR models you could do this. +1.

Comment: @FridoRolloos Thank you. I already upvoted your answer for mentioning the Clark–Ocone theorem, which I did not know. Looks very interesting. Would be cool to see whether it allows one to compute the variance in closed-form.

Answer (score 4):

A partial but general answer:

Let $\mathcal{F}_t^W$ be the filtration generated by $W$. Since $X_T = \int_t^T v_u du$ is $\mathcal{F}_T^W$ measurable, the Clark-Ocone-Haussman formula states
$$
X_T = E_t[X_T] + \int_t^T E_u \left[ D_u^W X_T \right] dW_u
$$
with $D_u^W X_T$ denoting the Malliavin derivative of $X_T$ with respect to $W_u$.

Hence,
$$
Var(X_T) = E_t \left[ \left( X_T - E_t[X_T] \right)^2 \right] = E_t \left[ \int_t^T \left( E_u \left( D_u^W X_T \right) \right)^2 du \right]
$$

I think the Malliavin derivative $D_u^W X_T$ can be calculated explicitly for the Heston model, and perhaps then also the expectation of integral on the right hand side. If I have time I'll check this for you and for myself.

I do not think there is a simpler way to calculate the variance exactly and in full generality.